# Bulk mail sending through amazon ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am sending bulk mails by using amazon SES. But I have certain issues and  please clarify some doubts regarding SES

1)while I am sending bulk mails as groups (max send limit is 50 at a time) I am getting json response with single unique message-id  for that 50 mails by using notification (SNS).How can I get 50 unique message id's for that 50 delivery mails.For further future reference I can check that unique id regarding that mail.

2)My second doubt is that while I am out of the sandbox I can send mails to recipients with out verifying  "TO" email address.In that scenario if I add 50 mails to destination what if my 50th mail is not a valid mail or that mail doesn't exist.Does my 49 mails reach to the destinations or that full process stops.
please clarify me on those things.Thanks in advance

```
Please check the sample json response:
{
  "notificationType":"Delivery",
  "mail":{
     "timestamp":"2014-05-28T22:40:59.638Z",
     "messageId":"0000014644fe5ef6-9a483358-9170-4cb4-a269-f5dcdf415321-000000",
     "source":"sender@example.com",
     "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:888888888888:identity/example.com",
     "sendingAccountId":"123456789012",
     "destination":[
        "success@simulator.amazonses.com",
        "recipient@example.com" 
     ]
  },
  "delivery":{
     "timestamp":"2014-05-28T22:41:01.184Z",
     "recipients":["success@simulator.amazonses.com"],
     "processingTimeMillis":546,     
     "reportingMTA":"a8-70.smtp-out.amazonses.com",
     "smtpResponse":"250 ok:  Message 64111812 accepted"
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) How did you configure your SNS Delivery Topic? How are you sending your emails? I use Sendy or a tool called Postman to send my emails and I'm getting unique message-id.

2)The sending process does not stop if, lets say, the email bounces or has an invalid email address. It will send a SNS message to either Complaints or Bounces topic.

Comment: 1)I have configured SNS through http

Comment: That is strange. Maybe you are getting only one id because you are sending the 50 emails simultaneously?

Comment: yeah,I am doing it simultaneously.suppose if i have to send email to one million receipents.I dont want to call the send mail() api call one million times.That is the reason I am sending max 50 mails for each api call.Am I doing anything wrong

Comment: I think that is the reason why you get only one id. I send them one by one, specially because you have a sending limit per second (mine is 4 emails per second, 70.000 emails daily).

Comment: Thanks nick.So, if you are sending 70k emails daily you need to do 70 k api calls.Can we do it in other way because if we do 70k api calls we have to use lot of threads.In my scenario atleast i have to send 4 lakh mails.And how to increase sending limit per second.

Comment: To increase sending limit per second you submit a request to AWS support.

Comment: Indeed, contact support. I understand, maybe this tool will help you? https://github.com/zachlatta/postman

Comment: Also, check that your email database is correct. Amazon is very strict with bounces and complaints.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion nick I will keep that in mind.

Comment: You are welcome! If you found my answer useful please accept it.

Comment: @NickG OP is using SES, not SNS.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, and how does SES handle its message notifications? With SNS

Comment: Hahahaha yes, my bad.  I read "SNS Delivery Topic" as the path to the email recipients rather than as the delivery notification topic and the entire conversation took a wrong turn in my head after that.  The correct answer, of course, is as you suggested -- if you want one message-id per recipient, you send to one recipient per message... which, incidentally, is the same cost as sending one to many.   1 message to 50 is the same price as 50 to 1 each.

Comment: No problem :) @Michael-sqlbot